# Django 1.10 Manually Commit to Database from CSV file record

Tags: python, django, csv, commit, atomic

I have a need to load to my model 11,000 sites with hourly temperature data for 7 days (so 7*24*11,000 data records) worth of data.  I need to do this twice a day.  Using autocommit is very slow.  I would like to commit after loading data from each site.  I have two model classes, Lake and Tempdat.  The essence of the code is below.   I appreciate any help you can provide.  I have been looking at atomic in the Django docs and other examples on this site, but I need more straightforward instruction (thanks!)

```
with open('iowa.csv', 'r+') as lakefile:
    lakes = csv.reader(lakefile)
    for lake in lakes:
        gnis = lake[0]

        temp_dat_filename = "T"+str(gnis)+".txt"
        nameanddir=os.path.join(tempdatdir,str(temp_dat_filename))
        f = open(nameanddir, 'r+')
        c = Lake.objects.get(GNIS=gnis) #Lake is the Class name
        print(c)

        for line in f:
            list_of_line = line.rstrip().split()
            date_pieces = list_of_line[0].split('-')

            dateob = datetime.datetime(int(date_pieces[0]), int(date_pieces[1]), int(date_pieces[2]), int(list_of_line[1]), 0, 0)
            temperature = list_of_line[2]
            #NOTE: instead of commiting here for each record, I would to go through all the records (7days worth, then commit)
            c.tempdat_set.create(LakeTemp = temperature, ModelDate = dateob)`
```

Comment: Django does not commit for each record.

Comment: So with the command: c.tempdat_set.create(LakeTemp = temperature, ModelDate = dateob), the data are not committed?  My understanding was that with past versions you could commit after saving or creating multiple records.  If this is not the case, is there way to increase the speed to this process

Comment: It doesn't seem at all like a django problem. It's more like with your algorithm. Please post your models and ad a few sample rows

Answer (score 0):

you can use `bulk_create`, should help -> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create

Comment: Thanks.  I understand that bulk_create does not overwrite existing data.  I am running a continuous model that will be projecting 7 days out and I want to overwrite the prediction every 12 hours.  If that is the case, any other ideas?